# Generate a P12 file with private key and certificate in an iOS app

Tags: ios, openssl

I have a certificate and private key that I want to put together, in code, into a PKCS12 file with the OpenSSL library (libcrypto). I know how to do this via the command-line tool:

```
$ openssl x509 -in developer_identity.cer -inform DER -out developer_identity.pem -outform PEM
$ openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -in mykey.p12 -out mykey.pem
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey mykey.key -in developer_identity.pem -out iphone_dev.p12
```

But how can I do it in code?

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to use C code in your objective-C code and you have OpenSSL library for iOS then you can do it.

You can use `PKCS12_create` function to create a `PKCS12` structure and write it to file using `i2d_PKCS12_bio` function.

`PKCS12_create` takes the certificate, private key, passphrase, chain of CA certificates and other parameter.

It is explained in a pretty well manner in [documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/PKCS12_create.html).

I hope this will help you to start coding.